# Crystal Reports Numeric Fields missing in Field Explorer (WPF and C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports in my WPF application to print invoice. When I use the field explorer and select the database object, the numeric fields are missing. When I converted those fields to varchar in SQL, its showing up. Is that a limitation in Crystal Reports, or is there any work around for this.

Thanks